# How do I call invokeLater or invokeAndWait in a BlackBerry / J2ME environment?

Tags: multithreading, blackberry

How do I call invokeLater or invokeAndWait in a BlackBerry / J2ME environment?  I'm using RIM API 4.3.  I know this is a basic question, but I can't find the method anywhere!

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Read this article [BlackBerry UI Threading - The Very Basics](http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/182)